# Can I join sys.columns to their data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

Pinal Dave has [this neat query](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/06/sql-server-query-to-find-column-from-all-tables-of-database/) where he finds all the columns named `EmployeeID` across all the tables in his database:

```
select t.name as table_name,
    schema_name(schema_id) as schema_name,
    c.name as column_name
from sys.tables as t
inner join sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
where c.name like '%EmployeeID%'
order by schema_name, table_name;
```

Is there a way to join that data to the data *in* the matched columns?

I've tried adding an additional `join` and looking through the other `sys.*` items to see if one of them sounded like it might be the data.

I have also tried constructing an outer `select` around this one, but that requires the `join`s to be in a format that (clearly) doesn't work:

```
select ( /* above */ ) as foo
inner join foo.table_name bar on bar.something = foo.something --???
```

Is there something else I can be doing? My ultimate aim is to update `EmployeeID` for *all* of the rows in *all* of the tables.

Comment: not without dynamic SQL

Comment: The tables themselves are the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, this can't be done as you are imagining, as data is stored in tables, and the catalog views (`sys.`) contain information about database objects.

You can achieve what you're after with a cursor and dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @col VARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@table VARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@schema VARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@strSQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE xyz CURSOR
FOR
        SELECT c.name
              ,t.name
              ,s.name
        FROM sys.tables t
        JOIN sys.columns c
         ON t.object_ID = c.object_ID
        JOIN sys.schemas s
         ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
        WHERE c.name LIKE '%EmployeeID%';    
OPEN xyz 
FETCH NEXT FROM xyz 
INTO @col,@table,@schema 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SET @strSQL = 
'UPDATE '+@schema+'.'+@table+' 
 SET '+@col+' = ''Something''
'
PRINT (@strSQL)

    FETCH NEXT FROM xyz 
    INTO @col,@table,@schema 
END
CLOSE xyz 
DEALLOCATE xyz 
GO
```

It's a good idea to test dynamic sql with the `PRINT` command before actually running it via `EXEC`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't in the way you seem to want.

Try writing code that generates T-SQL in something like [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). Or write code that generates dynamic SQL in T-SQL itself.